# Enable MySQL "Improved" extension from WHM without losing my data

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to install MySQL "Improved" extension from WHM on my dedicated server, however in order to do so need to install and enable MySQL "Improved" extension .

I can see that this can be done through EasyApache but I am concerned that if I rebuild Apache and PHP my websites will be deleted. Ideally I just want to rebuild PHP on its own but I can't see how to do this.

Can someone please tell me how to enable MySQL "Improved" extension without risking losing my data?

Thank you,

Comment: How about setting up a test-environment?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, you've not mentioned what platform you're using.